# Scraping wunderground without API, using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, wunderground

I'm not very experienced in the world of scraping data, so the problem here may be obvious to some.

What I want is to scrape historical daily weather data from wunderground.com, without paying the API. Maybe it's not possible at all.

My method is simply to use `requests.get` and save the whole text into a file (code below).

Instead of getting the tables that can be accessed from the web browser (see image below), the result is a file that has almost everything but those tables. Something like this:

**Summary**
No data recorded
**Daily Observations**
No Data Recorded

What is weird is that if I save-as the web page with Firefox, the result depends on whether I choose 'web-page, only HTML' or 'web-page, complete': the latter includes the data I'm interested in, the former does not.

Is it possible that this is on purpose so nobody scrapes their data? I just wanted to make sure there is not a workaround this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Juan

Note: I tried using the [user-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_identification) field to no avail.

```py
# Note: I run > set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 before executing python
import requests

# URL with wunderground weather information for a specific date:
date = '2019-03-12'
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/sd/khartoum/HSSS/date/' + date
r = requests.get(url)

# Write a file to check if the tables ar being retrieved:
with open('test.html', 'wb') as testfile:
    testfile.write(r.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

[image: Screenshot of the tables I want to scrape.]

---

**UPDATE: FOUND A SOLUTION**

Thanks to pointing me to the selenium module, it is the exact solution I needed. The code extracts all the tables present on the URL of a given date (as seen when visiting the site normally). It needs modifications in order to be able to scrape over a list of dates and organize the CSV files created.

**Note**: [geckodriver.exe](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) is needed in the working directory.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests, sys, re

# URL with wunderground weather information
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/sd/khartoum/HSSS/date/2019-3-12'

# Commands related to the webdriver (not sure what they do, but I can guess):
bi = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
br = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=bi)

# This starts an instance of Firefox at the specified URL:
br.get(url)

# I understand that at this point the data is in html format and can be
# extracted with BeautifulSoup:
sopa = BeautifulSoup(br.page_source, 'lxml')

# Close the firefox instance started before:
br.quit()

# I'm only interested in the tables contained on the page:
tablas = sopa.find_all('table')

# Write all the tables into csv files:
for i in range(len(tablas)):
    out_file = open('wunderground' + str(i + 1) + '.csv', 'w')
    tabla = tablas[i]

    # ---- Write the table header: ----
    table_head = tabla.findAll('th')
    output_head = []
    for head in table_head:
        output_head.append(head.text.strip())

    # Some cleaning and formatting of the text before writing:
    encabezado = '"' + '";"'.join(output_head) + '"'
    encabezado = re.sub('\s', '', encabezado) + '\n'
    out_file.write(encabezado.encode(encoding='UTF-8'))

    # ---- Write the rows: ----
    output_rows = []
    filas = tabla.findAll('tr')
    for j in range(1, len(filas)):
        table_row = filas[j]
        columns = table_row.findAll('td')
        output_row = []
        for column in columns:
            output_row.append(column.text.strip())

        # Some cleaning and formatting of the text before writing:
        fila = '"' + '";"'.join(output_row) + '"'
        fila = re.sub('\s', '', fila) + '\n'
        out_file.write(fila.encode(encoding='UTF-8'))

    out_file.close()
```

**Extra**: the answer of @QHarr works beautifully, but I needed a couple of modifications to use it, because I use firefox in my PC. It's important to note that for this to work I had to add the [geckodriver.exe](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) file into my working directory. Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/sd/khartoum/HSSS/date/2019-03-12'
bi = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=bi)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
tables = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table")))
for table in tables:
    newTable = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    if newTable:
        print(newTable[0].fillna(''))
```

Comment: This is a common scraping issue - most modern webpages are heavily reliant on javascript, which requires a VM to execute inside of. When you use requests, or `curl`, all you get is the raw html, without any of the functionality that the javascript provides. A good workaround for scraping is to use the selenium library, which gives you that javascript VM. It's a steep learning curve, but well worth it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the API? Аctually scraping via API much more easy and reliable.

Comment: @omegastripes : money

Comment: If you really want to scrape a webpage with JavaScript, you might want to use Selenium or something that can run an actual headless browser.

Comment: @Juan You can examine the webpage logged requests in a browser's developer tools and make some reverse engineering job to find out how to use the API for free.

Comment: @omegastripes that sounds like some 1337 h4x0r level stuff. I'd love to understand what you said but I don't quite much. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Juan That is quite simple stuff, take a look at [this](https://yadi.sk/i/WtigmOYwnnER_w)

Comment: Very cool @omegastripes! I'll give it a try one of this days. Thank you!

Comment: How do you bypass the `ValueError: No tables found matching pattern '.+'` error that comes up from @Qharr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use selenium to ensure page load then pandas read_html to get tables

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/sd/khartoum/HSSS/date/2019-03-12'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
tables = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table")))
for table in tables:
    newTable = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    if newTable:
        print(newTable[0].fillna(''))
```

Comment: This works beautifully, with some modifications for Firefox. Added an adapted version of your code in my post. Thanks!

Comment: How do you bypass the `ValueError: No tables found matching pattern '.+'` error that comes up?

Comment: With the same webpage?

Answer (score 4):

They have added some additional tables at the top, just searching with table will not work now, I have used the class selector with the class name to fetch the record, it's working fine

```
tables = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mat-table.cdk-table.mat-sort.ng-star-inserted")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another direction: Use the API calls that the website is doing.

(The HTTP call was taken from Chrome developer tools)

Example:

```
HTTP GET https://api-ak.wunderground.com/api/d8585d80376a429e/history_20180812/lang:EN/units:english/bestfct:1/v:2.0/q/HSSS.json?showObs=0&ttl=120
```

Response

```
{
    "response": {
        "version": "2.0",
        "units": "english",
        "termsofService": "https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
        "attribution": {
        "image":"//icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "features": {
        "history": 1
        }
        , "location": {
        "name": "Khartoum",
        "neighborhood":null,
        "city": "Khartoum",
        "state": null,
        "state_name":"Sudan",
        "country": "SD",
        "country_iso3166":"SA",
        "country_name":"Saudi Arabia",
        "continent":"AS",
        "zip":"00000",
        "magic":"474",
        "wmo":"62721",
        "radarcode":"xxx",
        "radarregion_ic":null,
        "radarregion_link": "//",
        "latitude":15.60000038,
        "longitude":32.54999924,
        "elevation":null,
        "wfo": null,
        "l": "/q/zmw:00000.474.62721",
        "canonical": "/weather/sa/khartoum"
        },
        "date": {
    "epoch": 1553287561,
    "pretty": "11:46 PM EAT on March 22, 2019",
    "rfc822": "Fri, 22 Mar 2019 23:46:01 +0300",
    "iso8601": "2019-03-22T23:46:01+0300",
    "year": 2019,
    "month": 3,
    "day": 22,
    "yday": 80,
    "hour": 23,
    "min": "46",
    "sec": 1,
    "monthname": "March",
    "monthname_short": "Mar",
    "weekday": "Friday",
    "weekday_short": "Fri",
    "ampm": "PM",
    "tz_short": "EAT",
    "tz_long": "Africa/Khartoum",
    "tz_offset_text": "+0300",
    "tz_offset_hours": 3.00
}
    }
        ,
"history": {
    "start_date": {
    "epoch": 1534064400,
    "pretty": "12:00 PM EAT on August 12, 2018",
    "rfc822": "Sun, 12 Aug 2018 12:00:00 +0300",
    "iso8601": "2018-08-12T12:00:00+0300",
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 8,
    "day": 12,
    "yday": 223,
    "hour": 12,
    "min": "00",
    "sec": 0,
    "monthname": "August",
    "monthname_short": "Aug",
    "weekday": "Sunday",
    "weekday_short": "Sun",
    "ampm": "PM",
    "tz_short": "EAT",
    "tz_long": "Africa/Khartoum",
    "tz_offset_text": "+0300",
    "tz_offset_hours": 3.00
},
    "end_date": {
    "epoch": null,
    "pretty": null,
    "rfc822": null,
    "iso8601": null,
    "year": null,
    "month": null,
    "day": null,
    "yday": null,
    "hour": null,
    "min": null,
    "sec": null,
    "monthname": null,
    "monthname_short": null,
    "weekday": null,
    "weekday_short": null,
    "ampm": null,
    "tz_short": null,
    "tz_long": null,
    "tz_offset_text": null,
    "tz_offset_hours": null
},
    "days": [
        {
        "summary": {
        "date": {
    "epoch": 1534021200,
    "pretty": "12:00 AM EAT on August 12, 2018",
    "rfc822": "Sun, 12 Aug 2018 00:00:00 +0300",
    "iso8601": "2018-08-12T00:00:00+0300",
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 8,
    "day": 12,
    "yday": 223,
    "hour": 0,
    "min": "00",
    "sec": 0,
    "monthname": "August",
    "monthname_short": "Aug",
    "weekday": "Sunday",
    "weekday_short": "Sun",
    "ampm": "AM",
    "tz_short": "EAT",
    "tz_long": "Africa/Khartoum",
    "tz_offset_text": "+0300",
    "tz_offset_hours": 3.00
},
        "temperature": 82,
    "dewpoint": 66,
    "pressure": 29.94,
    "wind_speed": 11,
    "wind_dir": "SSE",
    "wind_dir_degrees": 166,
    "visibility": 5.9,
    "humidity": 57,
    "max_temperature": 89,
    "min_temperature": 75,
    "temperature_normal": null,
    "min_temperature_normal": null,
    "max_temperature_normal": null,
    "min_temperature_record": null,
    "max_temperature_record": null,
    "min_temperature_record_year": null,
    "max_temperature_record_year": null,
    "max_humidity": 83,
    "min_humidity": 40,
    "max_dewpoint": 70,
    "min_dewpoint": 63,
    "max_pressure": 29.98,
    "min_pressure": 29.89,
    "max_wind_speed": 22,
    "min_wind_speed": 5,
    "max_visibility": 6.2,
    "min_visibility": 1.9,
    "fog": 0,
    "hail": 0,
    "snow": 0,
    "rain": 1,
    "thunder": 0,
    "tornado": 0,
    "snowfall": null,
    "monthtodatesnowfall": null,
    "since1julsnowfall": null,
    "snowdepth": null,
    "precip": 0.00,
    "preciprecord": null,
    "preciprecordyear": null,
    "precipnormal": null,
    "since1janprecipitation": null,
    "since1janprecipitationnormal": null,
    "monthtodateprecipitation": null,
    "monthtodateprecipitationnormal": null,
    "precipsource": "3Or6HourObs",
    "gdegreedays": 32,
    "heatingdegreedays": 0,
    "coolingdegreedays": 17,
    "heatingdegreedaysnormal": null,
    "monthtodateheatingdegreedays": null,
    "monthtodateheatingdegreedaysnormal": null,
    "since1sepheatingdegreedays": null,
    "since1sepheatingdegreedaysnormal": null,
    "since1julheatingdegreedays": null,
    "since1julheatingdegreedaysnormal": null,
    "coolingdegreedaysnormal": null,
    "monthtodatecoolingdegreedays": null,
    "monthtodatecoolingdegreedaysnormal": null,
    "since1sepcoolingdegreedays": null,
    "since1sepcoolingdegreedaysnormal": null,
    "since1jancoolingdegreedays": null,
    "since1jancoolingdegreedaysnormal": null
,
        "avgoktas": 5,
        "icon": "rain"
        }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but unfortunately I cannot understand this with my current knowledge. How would I run those commands? Is it windows cmd, unix command line, something else?

Answer (score 1):

I do it in the following manner.

I open developer tools using `Ctrl+Shift+I` Then I submit a request via the website while recording the transactions (In this case, you just click on the `View` button. Then I filter those for XHR. 
[image]

In the requests that remain, I go over the responses for each request that remain. The response that looked like the one I wanted I take its request URL and use it. It might be best to copy the response to a separate `JSON file` and beautify it so it's easy to read and determine if that's what you want.

In my scenario, my request URL was a get request to the following
https://api.weather.com/v1/location/OLBA:9:LB/observations/historical.json?apiKey=_____________&units=e&startDate=20200305

*I removed the API KEY from the URL above in order for me to use it*

When you paste the URL into a browser you should get the same response and then you can use Python requests package to get the response and just parse the JSON.